# non linear svm kernel dimension

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm, pattern-recognition

I have some problems with understanding the kernels for non-linear SVM. 
First what I understood by non-linear SVM is: using kernels the input is transformed to a very high dimension space where the transformed input can be separated by a linear hyper-plane.

Kernel for e.g: RBF:

```
         K(x_i, x_j) = exp(-||x_i - x_j||^2/(2*sigma^2));
```

where x_i and x_j are two inputs. here we need to change the sigma to adapt to our problem.

```
       (1) Say if my input dimension is d, what will be the dimension of the 
           transformed space?

       (2) If the transformed space has a dimension of more than 10000 is it 
           effective to use a linear SVM there to separate the inputs?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is not only a matter of increasing the dimension. That's the general mechanism but not the whole idea, if it were true that the only goal of the kernel mapping is to increase the dimension, one could conclude that all kernels functions are equivalent and they are not.

The way how the mapping is made would make possible a linear separation in the new space.
Talking about your example and  just to extend a bit what greeness said, RBF kernel would order the feature space in terms of hyperspheres where an input vector would need to be close to an existing sphere in order to produce an activation.

So to answer directly your questions:

1) Note that you don't work on feature space directly. Instead, the optimization problem is solved using the inner product of the vectors in the feature space, so computationally you won't increase the dimension of the vectors.

2) It would depend on the nature of your data, having a high dimensional pattern would somehow help you to prevent overfitting but not necessarily will be linearly separable. Again, the linear separability in the new space would be achieved because the way the map is made and not only because it is in a higher dimension. In that sense, RBF would help but keep in mind that it might not perform well on generalization if your data is not locally enclosed.

Answer (score 2):

The transformation usually increases the number of dimensions of your data, not necessarily very high. It depends. The RBF Kernel is one of the most popular kernel functions. It adds a "bump" around each data point. The corresponding feature space is a Hilbert space of **infinite** dimensions.

It's hard to tell if a transformation into 10000 dimensions is effective or not for classification without knowing the specific background of your data. However, choosing a good mapping (encoding prior knowledge + getting right complexity of function class) for your problem improves results.

For example, the [MNIST database of handwritten digits](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) contains 60K training examples and 10K test examples with 28x28 binary images.

- Linear SVM has ~8.5% test error.
- Polynomial SVM has ~ 1% test error.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a very natural one that almost everyone who's learned about kernel methods has asked some variant of. However, I wouldn't try to understand what's going on with a non-linear kernel in terms of the implied feature space in which the linear hyperplane is operating, because most non-trivial kernels have feature spaces that it is very difficult to visualise.

Instead, focus on understanding the [kernel trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick), and think of the kernels as introducing a particular form of non-linear decision boundary in input space. Because of the kernel trick, and some fairly daunting maths if you're not familiar with it, any kernel function satisfying certain properties can be viewed as operating in some feature space, *but the mapping into that space is never performed*. You can read the following (fairly) accessible tutorial if you're interested: [from zero to Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces in twelve pages or less](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.184.3451).

Also note that because of the formulation in terms of slack variables, the hyperplane does not have to separate points exactly: there's an objective function that's being maximised which contains penalties for misclassifying instances, but some misclassification can be tolerated if the margin of the resulting classifier on most instances is better. Basically, we're optimising a classification rule according to some criteria of:

1. how big the margin is
2. the error on the training set

and the SVM formulation allows us to solve this efficiently. Whether one kernel or another is better is very application-dependent (for example, text classification and other language processing problems routinely show best performance with a linear kernel, probably due to the extreme dimensionality of the input data). There's no real substitute for trying a bunch out and seeing which one works best (and make sure the SVM hyperparameters are set properly---[this talk by one of the LibSVM authors has the gory details](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/freiburg.pdf)).